# How to downgrade Wampserver PHP and Apache?

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wampserver

I have a project that runs on Apache 2.2.21 and PHP 5.3.10. I installed the latest wampserver which have Apache 2.4.4 and PHP 5.4.16. How can I downgrade the version?

I also have a project that runs in the latest and not in the old version that's why I can't install the old version of wampserver. In my wampserver I installed the Apache and PHP which is old version. But after installing it and restarting my server. I can't run the Apache and PHP. If I start the version of Apache it says the PHP version is not compatible. And if I enable the PHP it says the Apache is not compatible with the version of Apache.

Can you give me an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

left click wamp> php>version> get more>

select the version ytou want and download it.

install the exe.

left click wamp> php> version> php xxx.x

UPDATE: I have further investigated: to switch between that 2 version seems not that simple... please [check this guide](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,119698), it has very detailed information

[and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18704910/wamp-server-errors-switching-apache-php-versions-on-fresh-install) maybe also help

[image]

Comment: I already downloaded and install the old version of PHP but I can't start it. I always got an error about compatibility with Apache version.

Comment: some php requiere specific version of apache to run it. I think you have to install both apache and php versions

Comment: I already installed the old Apache and PHP. But I can't start them. :(

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer. I will accept it. I just need to study how to switch them. Thanks for the reference. :)

Comment: addons tab is removed

Comment: I made the mistake of trying to do a multiple PHP and Apache install in Wamp and it was a nightmare. My advice: do a backup of all your configuration files, uninstall wamp and everything related and then go to the sourcefourge web site of wamp and choose an older versions (not the outdated) of wamp. The version of apache, php and mysql is shown in each version, so you can choose which one is the one you need. This will take you like 5 minutes, instead of the three hours I wasted trying to pull this off.

Comment: Use e.g. C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin>httpd.exe -t to check the syntax of your conf files

Answer (score 1):

Just go to [wamp home page](http://www.wampserver.com/en/). At the bottom of the page you'll find links (big yellow buttons, you can't miss them)  towards apache and PHP addons. Install some of them and you'll be able to be between several versions of apache and PHP from wamp's menu.

Comment: I already did that. But I can't start the version of Apache and PHP I downloaded.

Comment: I just downloaded the latest wampserver 64 bits, apache 2.2.1 addon and PHP 5.3.1 addon. I installed them in this order, and it works. I just add a problem with the curl extension that is not loaded due to a config problem as an error message told me, but it does not prevent the server to work.

Comment: i cannot find apache and PHP addons.