# Installing Wordpress 2.2.1 on Windows 8.1

Tags: wordpress, wamp, wampserver

I'm trying to install a site with Wordpress 2.2.1 on a PC with Windows 8.1, I get a bunch of errors telling me that several functions are deprecated. What is the best way of achieving this, do I install a older version of wamp? or will I have to install windows xp or vista?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Tip, it is your PHP version. But I wouldn't recommand to use the old deprecated version of PHP nor Wordpress.

Comment: Thank you, I wouldn't use it too but there's an old site I need to get data from it

Comment: Allright, you can look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22237695/how-to-downgrade-wampserver-php-and-apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install an older version on wamp on your PC it should work, worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your localhost/localserver (WAMP). It must have php 5.5 or greater.

Comment: He's trying to install an very old WordPress, so he has to download a very old version of WAMP for that

Comment: but this site was online during 2007 so maybe I though it should have lower versions of PHP

Comment: wp2.21 is compatible with php 5.5 because newer version supports older version. :-)