# Modx Evo - After copy from webserver to localhost manager login not possible anymore

Tags: php, modx, modx-evolution

I am using the latest WAMPServer64 with PHP 5.5.12.

What I did: From a webserver (runs PHP 5.4.16) I have copied the modx folders to localhost, then I copied the entire database. I have also changed the database credentials accordingly via `manager/includes/confic.inc.php`.

When opening the manager login, I see the following:

> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in \manager\includes\extenders\dbapi.mysql.class.inc.php on line 93

When I try to login, the manager does not show up and I get a bunch of errors, content of php_error.log:

```
PHP Deprecated:  mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in manager\includes\extenders\dbapi.mysql.class.inc.php on line 93

PHP Stack trace:

PHP   1. {main}() manager\processors\login.processor.php:0

PHP   2. DBAPI->escape() manager\processors\login.processor.php:51

PHP   3. DBAPI->connect() manager\includes\extenders\dbapi.mysql.class.inc.php:156

PHP   4. mysql_connect() manager\includes\extenders\dbapi.mysql.class.inc.php:93

PHP Notice:  Undefined index: captcha_code in manager\processors\login.processor.php on line 53

PHP Stack trace:

PHP   1. {main}() manager\processors\login.processor.php:0

PHP Notice:  Undefined index: rememberme in manager\processors\login.processor.php on line 54

PHP Stack trace:

PHP   1. {main}() manager\processors\login.processor.php:0

PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: allowed_ip in manager\processors\login.processor.php on line 134

PHP Stack trace:

PHP   1. {main}() manager\processors\login.processor.php:0

PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: allowed_days in manager\processors\login.processor.php on line 148

PHP Stack trace:

PHP   1. {main}() manager\processors\login.processor.php:0

PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: newloginerror in manager\processors\login.processor.php on line 224

PHP Stack trace:

PHP   1. {main}() manager\processors\login.processor.php:0

PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at manager\processors\login.processor.php:54) in manager\processors\login.processor.php on line 298

PHP Stack trace:

PHP   1. {main}() manager\processors\login.processor.php:0

PHP   2. setcookie() manager\processors\login.processor.php:298

PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: sql in manager\includes\extenders\dbapi.mysql.class.inc.php on line 276

PHP Stack trace:

PHP   1. {main}() manager\processors\login.processor.php:0

PHP   2. logHandler->initAndWriteLog() manager\processors\login.processor.php:302

PHP   3. logHandler->writeToLog() manager\includes\log.class.inc.php:42

PHP   4. DBAPI->insert() manager\includes\log.class.inc.php:76
```

I have searched for solutions on the net, some suggested to clear the cache, which is not directly possible since the manager interface does not load. I also tried to upgrade using the default install folder, same problem remains.

So if anyone has a clue how I can solve this without installing an old version of PHP, that would be great.

Comment: The cache should be physical, isn't it? So there should be a "cache"-folder somewhere in your project-folder. Did you try clearing it's content?

Comment: Yes, I have removed all files from `\assets\cache`, same errors as above. I also copied the cache folder from the fresh installation, same problem.

Comment: clearing the cache won't help. you either upgraded to a newer mysql on the local machine, or your other machine has warnings disabled - the warnings are NOT going to away without fixing the code to NOT use the deprecated mysql_*() functions.

Comment: Now I have done the following: 1. Clear install of ModX Evo 1.0.15 on localhost with a new db, 2. then changing the database in `manager/includes/confic.inc.php` ($dbase) to the original database. Now I can login. 3. Problem: These are not the files from the webserver, I'd need to compare both for the same files/modules/etc. However, for simple testing purpose it might be sufficient. 4. Nevertheless, I would really like to know a direct solution to the problem above.

Comment: Did you try one of the two mentioned solutions in my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31122537/1166642 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get rid of the mysql deprecated warning you have to use Evo 1.0.15+ and you should change

```
$database_type = 'mysql';
```

to

```
$database_type = 'mysqli';
```

in config.inc.php

The 'only' thing that uses the old mysql_ functions is the installer then. The deprecated warnings are disabled in there for PHP 5.5.

Comment: Due to your fix above the manager shows up, thanks a thousand Jako.

Sidenode: modx then tried to load `includes/extenders/dbapi.mysqli.class.inc.php` (mysqli) which did not exist on my localhost. Obviously when copying from the webserver to my localhost not all files were copied.

Answer (score 0):

MODx Evolution has a lot of old code in it. As you see by your warnings it is using [deprecated mysql-functions](http://php.net/manual/function.mysql-connect.php). This is long known in the [MODx Forums](http://forums.modx.com/thread/87015/evo-doesn-t-work-with-php-5-5-x).

As for now you have two possible solutions:

- [Downgrade your local php version via WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22237695/how-to-downgrade-wampserver-php-and-apache) to some (best, the same) PHP 5.4 version.
- [Change your PHP error-reporting level](http://forums.modx.com/thread/87015/evo-doesn-039-t-work-with-php-5-5-x#dis-post-480279) (inside the affected files or in your [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php)) to omit deprecated errors, as long as Evo has [this issue](https://github.com/modxcms/evolution/issues/171).

Comment: Solution 1: Did not work, WAMP server x64 did not accept the PHP 5.4 packages I tried. 
Solution 2: Did not work, I added the `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED); ` to both stated fileds, still the deprecated warning appears.

Comment: Did you download the PHP package from the official "Get more..." button? (updated post with link to SO-post) Adjusting the error_reporting should actually work - If you'd do it right, in the right spot, the warnings definitely  shouldn't appear any more.

Answer (score 0):

Can check following  solution
https://toster.ru/q/125593

really works !
:)